# Faster Way to Code this MysQL Query using GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT, ORDER BY and 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, having

I am trying to use this to query 2 tables and get results based on factors from mainly one table.  I would prefer doing 1 query instead of 1 query with many sub queries in a while or foreach.

```
SELECT a.request, a.city 
FROM pages a, TNDB_CSV2 b
WHERE a.main_id = b.PerformerID 
AND b.PCatID = '3' 
AND a.catnum = '303' 
AND a.city = b.City 
AND b.TicketsYN = 'Y' 
AND b.CountryID IN ('38', '217')  
GROUP BY b.PerformerID, b.City HAVING COUNT(*) > 4 
ORDER BY a.name ASC
```

So basically what this is saying is that I want to get results in 'pages' where records in 'TNDB_CSV2' have at least 4 matches of 'PerformerID' and 'City'.

The query works correctly, the issue is that it takes between 55-67 seconds to run which is massively way too long.  Similar queries should take a fraction of a second.  I have never grouped by 2 columns using HAVING and COUNT before so I am thinking there might be a much more efficient way of doing this.

The query currently returns 1,011 records and I looked to make sure that the conditions match the results and they do.

Comment: Please stop using non-ANSI `GROUP BY` syntax.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Okay... Thank you, How about an alternative?  Is this what is causing the lag?

Comment: Please provide the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements so as to easily create the table and populate it (ideally, a sqlfiddle.net link) @FreshPrinceOfSO: you talk about including group by fields in select statement, isn't it? Or there is something more I'm missing?

Comment: Or maybe you can just post a common table expression (CTE) for pages and tnb_csv2?

Comment: How large are the tables?  How big is the result set, both with and without the `having` clause?

Comment: If you're not using an aggregate, you should not be using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please post the `EXPLAIN` output for your query.

Comment: The tables are 30,000 and 75,000 rows +/-

Comment: @GordonLinoff The result set is twice the size (2,200) results when I remove the having clause.

Comment: @NotJay . . . Those are not particularly large.  Either the indexes will work ok, or there may be an issue with your join -- you might be missing one or more common keys between the tables which is multiplying your output before the aggregation inadvertently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added additional indexes to the tables.  The query load time is now down to about 6 seconds.  I feel like it could be faster still.  There should not be any additional correlations between the 2 tables and I don't believe I am getting duplicate or unwanted results.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query, formatted with a proper `join` clause:

```
SELECT a.request, a.city 
FROM pages a join
     TNDB_CSV2 b
     on a.main_id = b.PerformerID and a.city = b.City 
WHERE b.PCatID = '3' AND 
      b.TicketsYN = 'Y' AND
      b.CountryID IN ('38', '217')  and
      a.catnum = '303'   
GROUP BY b.PerformerID, b.City
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4 
ORDER BY a.name ASC;
```

You should be able to improve the performance of this query with indexes.  Here are two that I can think of:

```
pages(catnum, main_id, city, name)
TNDB_CSV2(PerformerID, city, PCatID, TicketsYN, CountryID);
```

Comment: Some indexes already existed but I added others and now I'm looking at a load time of less than 6seconds which is still a little high.  I also reformed my mysql query as you suggested.  This certainly helped!  Thank you